# facebook c# sdk how to post to user's wall as application from wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'd like to know, how can I use facebook c# sdk to post to user's wall from my wp7 app as application.
So I want to display message from FB application on users wall.

I have so far:

```
var app = new FacebookApp();
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                 {
                     {"access_token", accessToken},
                     {"appId", appId,
                     {"message", "TEST"}
                 };
var fbCB = new FacebookAsyncCallback(postResult);
app.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters, fbCB);
```

But this displays text on my wall as I wrote it, not like the application specified by appId.

Comment: I want to post same message type to wall like the one bellow, but without user interaction:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
But user will not be prompted, just

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.PostAsync("friendId/feed", parameters, fbCB);
```

I would also suggest you to use the latest facebook c# sdk.

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.1.0 available through NuGet